# How to fire a scroll event in `infinite-scroll` on a custom height div?

Tags: angular, typescript, infinite-scroll

I m trying an angular module with infinite scroll fetching data from an open API source.

Although the infinite scroll works perfectly fine, the moment I manipulate the height of the said `DIV` (in px or %) the `scroll` function stops triggering.

*Below is the code for the same :*

**comp.html:**

```
<div class="sub_div"
    infinite-scroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="1000"
    (scrolled)="onScrolls()"
    >
        <p *ngFor="let item of items" style="padding:25% 0">{{ item.name }}</p>
</div>
```

**comp.scss:**

```
.sub_div {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background: lightblue;
}
```

**comp.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Item } from '../item.model';
import { ItemService } from '../item.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-page2',
  templateUrl: './page2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page2.component.scss']
})
export class Page2Component implements OnInit {
  title = 'page 2';
  
  page = 1;
  items: Item[] = []

  constructor(private itemservice: ItemService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.itemservice
      .getItems(this.page)
      .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
        this.items = items;
      });
  }

  onScrolls() {
    this.itemservice
      .getItems(++this.page)
      .subscribe((items: Item[]) => {
        this.items.push(...items);
      });
      console.log(1);
  }
}
```

**item.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Item } from './item.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ItemService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getItems(page: number): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds?page=${page}&limit=5`) as Observable<Item[]>;
  }
  
}
```

**The error I get for the above code :**

*`None..`*

**What works:**

- The moment I comment out the height property in css, the `onScrolls()` triggers and loads more data on scroll to bottom of div (i.e, window),
- But when I resize the div with px or % to even 90% of the window size, only `ngOnInit()` not the later on scroll to bottom.

**P.S** *( I even tried `cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport` but the problem with that is, it removes the rendered elements as you scroll down more. and re-renders them back when you scroll up again, which is not what I'm looking for.)*

Hope I was clear.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you manipulate te div height? Can you share the code? And if you are trying to assign "%" better will be to use "vh" instead

Comment: Hi, i assigned a height property to div `.sub_div` in `comp.scss` (included above)

Comment: Ok then try to assign the height to a wrapping / parent div and position inside it the infinite-scroll one without manipulating the sizes

Comment: and try without "overflow-y: auto" I belive the infinite-scroll library is going to take care about such things